# Reduce http requests or load data from database partially

Tags: http, time, load, maps

I have this site and i want to reduce the http requests, www.dealsonmap.gr, how can i do this to reduce load time?

i have checked the site on pingdom tools and its says me that it has 600 plus requests!

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your site makes 127 requests to server and requests are slow to initiliaze.

Reduce the number of .css and .js files and it will make it faster to download.

- Concatinate all .css files into one file *(9 .css requests)*
- Take similar images (fb, g+,  tw) and group them together into images containing array of images and use `background-position` css attribute to access them (71 image requests)
- If possible concatinate javascript files into bigger .js files *(27 .js requests)*

Comment: If this post answered your question, please select it as answer